Is $X\times X$ homeomorphic to $X$ for a space of probability measures?
Let $\mathcal M_1(S)$ be the (compact, metrizable) space of probability Borel measures on the circle $S=\{z\in\mathbb C: |z|=1\}$ with its weak $*$ topology, so $\mu_n\to\mu$ if and only if
$$
\int_S f\, d\mu_n\to \int_S f\, d\mu
$$
for all $f\in C(S)$.
Is $\mathcal M_1(S)\times \mathcal M_1(S)$ homeomorphic to $\mathcal M_1(S)$?

If instead you considered a norm topology on the space of measures, it seems that the answer is yes, since there is a Borel bijection between $S$ and $S\cup S$.

Yes, I understand, just wrote it for the people who might've thought of the other problem.

Also just to be sure, do you want just a topological homeomorphism or a linear one?

@AlekseiKulikov: We can clearly not preserve the linear structure since $\mathcal M_1(S)$ has extreme points ${ \delta_x}\cong S$, which is not homeomorphic to $S\sqcup S$.

@AlekseiKulikov I’m a bit confused. $\mathcal{M}_1(S)\times\mathcal{M}_1(S)$ is not (affinely homeomorphic to) $\mathcal{M}_1(S\sqcup S)$. How is isomorphism between $S$ and $S\sqcup S$ relevant?

@DavidGao if we endow them with total variation norm (so that all $\delta$ measures are 2 apart from each other) then I think sending a measure $\mu$ to measure $\nu$ with $\mu(f(X)) = \nu(X)$ where $f$ is our bijection should work, no? This will even be an isometry.

@AlekseiKulikov I’m not disputing that $\mathcal{M}_1(S)$ and $\mathcal{M}_1(S\sqcup S)$ are isometric under the total variation norm, which seems to be what you have shown. But why is the latter space homeomorphic to $\mathcal{M}_1(S)\times\mathcal{M}_1(S)$? They are clearly not affinely homeomorphic since $\mathcal{M}_1(S\sqcup S)$ has extreme points $S\sqcup S$ while $\mathcal{M}_1(S)\times\mathcal{M}_1(S)$ has extreme points $S\times S$.

@AlekseiKulikov Agreeing with David Gao, try thinking about the two-point space instead of $S$, where $\mathcal{M}_1(2) \times \mathcal{M}_1(2)$ is a square, but $\mathcal{M}_1(2 + 2)$ is a tetrahedron. In general $\mathcal{M}_1(X) \times \mathcal{M}_1(Y)$ is not a space of probability measures but the state space of the coproduct order-unit space $C(X) \oplus C(Y)$.

Aha, I see, the property of being a probability measure is not preserved under the transformation I thought of. Thanks everyone!

The answer is yes, following from Klee's extension of Keller's theorem on homeomorphisms of infinite dimensional compact convex sets:
Klee, V. L., Some topological properties of convex sets, Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 78, 30-45 (1955). ZBL0064.10505.
Specifically, combining (1.1) with the theorem of Keller:

If $K$ is an infinite-dimensional compact convex subset of $E$, a topological vector space, such that there is a countable set $F \subseteq E^*$ separating the points of $K$, then $K$ is homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube.

(For the avoidance of doubt, I use $E^*$ to mean the space of continuous linear functionals throughout)
For $\mathcal{M}_1(S)$, consider it inside $C(S)^*$ with the weak-* topology and take $F$ to be your favourite countable norm-dense subset of $C(S)$, considered as weak-* continuous maps $C(S)^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. For $\mathcal{M}_1(S) \times \mathcal{M}_1(S)$, consider it inside the product topological vector space $C(S)^* \times C(S)^*$ with the product of weak-* topologies (the underlying Banach space is the $\ell^\infty$-direct sum). Define
$$
F' = \{ \phi \circ \pi_1 \mid \phi \in F \} \cup \{ \phi \circ \pi_2 \mid \phi \in F \}
$$
where $\pi_1 : E \times F \rightarrow E$ and $\pi_2 : E \times F \rightarrow F$ are the usual projection maps. Then $F'$ is a countable subset of $(C(S)^* \times C(S)^*)^*$ separating the points of $\mathcal{M}_1(S) \times \mathcal{M}_1(S)$, so this is also homeomorphic to the Hilbert cube and therefore to $\mathcal{M}_1(S)$.

Thank you, this is very useful for me. In the last part, we could also just use that (obviously) $H\times H\cong H$ for the Hilbert cube $H=[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$.
